# How to make background on <li> tags the same for a dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a simple drop down menu from scratch, and after reading a few similar problems I can't seem to fix my specific problem.

The problem is has other mention, making the background of the drop down menu the same width for all menu items.

This is the code I'm running now: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uxckd/)

HTML:

```
<div class="menu_container">
            <ul> 
                <li><a class="menu_item" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><a class="menu_item" href="#">Work</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="menu_item_drop" href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                        <li><a class="menu_item_drop" href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                        <li><a class="menu_item_drop" href="#">Animation</a></li>
                        <li><a class="menu_item_drop" href="#">Sound Design/Music</a></li>
                        <li><a class="menu_item_drop" href="#">Game Development</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><a class="menu_item" href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li>|</li>
                <li><a class="menu_item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu_container{
    width: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.menu_container ul li{ 
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    }

.menu_item{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#999;
    padding: 2px;
    }

.menu_item_selected{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    }


.menu_item:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 2px;   
}

.menu_container ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 1px;
    }

.menu_container ul li ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    }

.menu_container ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    }

.menu_container ul li:hover > ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 140px;
    top: -12px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

.menu_item_drop{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ddd;
    background-color: #111;
    padding: 12px;
    }

.menu_item_drop:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
    background-color: #bbb;
    padding: 12x;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.menu_container{
    width: 750px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


.menu_container ul li{ 
    list-style:none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    }

.menu_item{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#999;
    padding: 2px;
    }

.menu_item_selected{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 2px;
    }


.menu_item:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 2px;   
}

.menu_container ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    }

.menu_container ul li ul li{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #111111;
    padding: 12px;
    }

.menu_container ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    }

.menu_container ul li:hover > ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 140px;
    top: -12px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 12px;
    }

.menu_container ul li > ul li:hover{
    background-color: #bbb;
}

.menu_container ul li > ul li:hover a{
    color: #000;
}

.menu_item_drop{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#ddd;
    }

.menu_item_drop:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222;
    }
```

the main changes were moving the background color and padding from the a to the li, and removing the margins from the nested li (drop down)

http://jsfiddle.net/uxckd/2/

Comment: Thanks, that totally did it. I knew it had to be something simple, but since I'm not an expert I tend to get lost in some of the code, which was probably a bit confusing.

Thank you for the help.